# Line segment straddle

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

What is exactly the definition of "Straddle"?

Can you please explain what do they mean exactly or a sketch? A segment P1P2 Straddles a line if point P1 lies on the one side of the line and point P2 lies on the other side. A boundary case of P1 or P2 lies directly on the line. **(Taken from Introduction to algorithms 3rd)**

After a couple of answers:
[image]

Comment: The sentence you give actually is a definition.

Comment: Well I didn't Understand the definition that's why I am asking. I mean it's obvious that I didn't understand it

Comment: What isn't so obvious is where your understanding breaks down.  A line (let's call it L) divides the plane into two parts (half-planes is a term we use).  A line *segment* has two endpoint, say P1 and P2.  If the two endpoints are neither of them on the line, and instead the two endpoints are in different parts of the plane as divided by L (different half-planes), then we say the line segment P1P2 "straddles" line L.  If you've ever straddled a bicycle, you know about having your two feet on opposite sides of the bicycle.

Comment: ohhh  now I get it!! ok ok I understand, let me plot it. 

Thank you @hardmath, can you add your answer as solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line L separates the plane into two half-planes.  That is, removing L leaves two (unbounded) regions on either side of L.

We may use the word *straddle* to describe a line segment that connects these two half-planes by having an endpoint P1 or P2 in each of the two separated regions.  Visually we see that line segment P1P2 crosses line L and defines a point of intersection strictly between the two endpoints P1 and P2.